# Making a user defined function run for an array of elements?

Tags: r

I'm getting a warning message and a wrong answer when i try to run my function for a list of elements or a part of data frame. It is perfectly running for a single number.

```
library(bezier)
t <- seq(0, 1, length=100)
p <- matrix(c(0.03,0.03,0, 0.335,0.6,0, 0.667,0.9,0, 1,1,0), nrow=4, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
bezier_points <- bezier(t=t, p=p[, 1:2])


getybezier <- function(x, bezpointsdf) 
{
  ind <- min(which(bezpointsdf[,1] > x))
  return(bezier_points[ind,2])
}

getybezier(0.45, bezier_points)
test <- c(0.031, 0.45, 0.65)
getybezier(test, bezier_points)
```

> getybezier(0.45, bezier_points)
>   [1] 0.6358359
>   test <- c(0.031, 0.45, 0.65)
>   getybezier(test, bezier_points)
>   [1] 0.03205104
>   Warning message:
>   In bezpointsdf[, 1] > x :
>     longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Is there a way by which i can remove this warning message? It gives me the wrong answer. I know the reason why it does so. However, i don't know how to correct this. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it is returning an error is that the function does not know how to handle an object longer than 1 for the x argument in the function you defined, which is for the best in terms of performance. You can accomplish running this function over multiple test values by using the `apply` family of funtions.

If you want your output to be in a list, you can use `lapply()`:

```
lapply(test, getybezier, bezpointsdf = bezier_points)
```

which gives you:

```
> lapply(test, getybezier, bezpointsdf = bezier_points)
[[1]]
[1] 0.04719015

[[2]]
[1] 0.6361454

[[3]]
[1] 0.8233659
```

Or, if you want the output in a vector, you can use `sapply()`:

```
sapply(test, getybezier, bezpointsdf = bezier_points)
```

which gives you:

```
> sapply(test, getybezier, bezpointsdf = bezier_points)
[1] 0.04719015 0.63614540 0.82336591
```